# how can i display input value in blade LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i need to display selected option in blade and set it in a value here's my code as an exemple.

```
@php($month = 0)
            <select name="monthOption" id="monthOption">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
<!-- I need to get option value on select, and set it in the value $month ? -->

{{$month}}
```

Comment: Using `javascript` you can store value in to a variable with `onchange function`. Is that what you expect

Comment: i did not understand what's your problem

Comment: i don't want to use Javascript, i need it by using PHP

Comment: all what i need is: when i select an option from select box should display using PHP. for example if i select option with value 1 
i want to get number 1 shown. that's it :) 

Thanks for helping me

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking for something impossible. Your PHP code has already finished running by the time the page is loaded and the user is able to interact with the `<select>`. You can't change page content in response to UI events using pure PHP; you *need* to use JavaScript.

Comment: You can do it with a page refresh if you want use php. if you like so i can submit my answer.

Comment: You only get the value from html after the form submit or change event bu javascript

Comment: I found a solution is to use Javascript when i select option and click on submit, i get the value selected with Js.

Thanks for your helps guys :)